# How to output data with ids matching selected data ID?

Tags: javascript, api, drop-down-menu, frameworks, output

I want to output a list based on what the user has selected in the drop-down menu. Each genre in the menu has a unique ID as do all the individual movies. The problem I'm having is connecting the two or creating a function that will output the results I want.

So far what happens is when you select a genre, it only outputs the selected Genres ID number. I also made a separate list that outputs random movies and their information, but the two are not connected. You can call the individual moves by using movie.genre_ids.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.getMovies();
    this.getGenres();

      fetch(BASE_URL)
      .then(response => {
        return response.json().then(json => {
          return response.ok ? json : Promise.reject(json);
        });
      })

      .then((data) => {
          var movies = [];
          console.log('Success', JSON.stringify(data));
          movies.push({"movieinfo":data})
          this.setState({movies : data.results,loading:false});
           alert("Total pages= " + data.total_pages)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            alert(error);
        });           
  }

  handleGenreChange(e) {
    this.setState({ selectedGenre: e.target.value})

  }

render() {
    return (
     <div class="list-style">
          <select type='text' value={this.state.selectedGenre} 
                 onChange={this.handleGenreChange}>
            {this.state.genres.map((item, index)=>(
            <option key={item.id} value={item.id}>{item.name}</option>
            ))}
          </select>
          {this.state.selectedGenre} 
    </div>
```

So basically I want to create a function that will output only the movies with the matching ID to the genre ID that is selected. I've been trying various ways to do this but I feel like I'm over-complicating everything.(I'm very very new to this so please forgive me for not using proper terms & probably asking a stupid question.)

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is u need to check in genres array if selected id is present or not and if yes than set selectedGenre as a object of id and name.

```
handleGenreChange(e) {
    this.state.genres.map((item, index)=>(
            if(item.id === e.target.value) {
               this.setState({
                 selectedGenre: item
               })
            }
     ))
  }
```

you also need to change value in `<select>` as mentioned below  and print the name of Movie as shown below

```
<div class="list-style">
          <select type='text' value={this.state.selectedGenre.id} 
                 onChange={this.handleGenreChange}>
            {this.state.genres.map((item, index)=>(
            <option key={item.id} value={item.id}>{item.name}</option>
            ))}
          </select>
          {this.state.selectedGenre.name} 
    </div>
```

I hope this works for you

Comment: Thanks! This worked for a bit but I had to change a lot of my code eventually.